# Having two different leaflet popup styles simultaneously

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, leaflet

I was wondering if it is possible to have two completely different styles of popup. Here is an example: [Solid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqZXb.png) [Transparent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTcTh.png)
I want to use both of those styles independently of each other. For example have the solid background for a rectangle and transparent for a marker. This is the code that changes it to transparent:

```
.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
    background: #D3D3D3;
    background: transparent;
}
```

Thank you for any information you can provide for this noob :)

EDIT: I tried to go the way @n0m4d suggested by adding a class to my popup, however it did not seem to do anything:

JS:

```
var popup = L.popup({className: 'pareina'})
    .setLatLng([0, 0])
    .setContent("I am a standalone popup.")
    .openOn(map);
```

CSS:

```
.pareina{
    background: black;
}
```

**EDIT2: I managed to get it to work, here is what I did:**

JS:

```
var popup = L.popup({className: 'pareina'})
    .setLatLng([0, 0])
    .setContent("I am a standalone popup.")
    .openOn(map);
```

CSS this is where I did things a bit differently:

```
.pareina .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper{
    background: transparent;
}
```

basically I made `.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper` a child element of `.pareina` and it worked! :) thank you for helping @n0m4d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to leaflet's js [docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup-l.popup), you can pass in a class name into the popup options:

> className option: A custom class name to assign to the popup.

So your code would look like something like this:

```
var popup = L.popup({className: 'leaflet-popup-content-wrapper' })
             .setLatLng(latlng)
             .setContent('<p>Hello world!<br />This is a nice popup.</p>')
             .openOn(map);
```

Comment: `var popup = L.popup({className: 'pareina'})
    .setLatLng([0, 0])
    .setContent("I am a standalone popup.")
    .openOn(map); `
that is what I used to add a class to my popup, then used this in my CSS file: 
` .pareina{
    background: black;
} `
Did not seem to do anything.

Comment: have you tried L.popup({className: '.pareina'})? They didn't specify if we had to use .className or just className.